# How to create thiessen polygons from points using R packages?

Tags: r, geometry, polygon, spatial

I have multiple sets of points (for different years ~20)

I want to generate thiessen polygons for each set of points using r spatial packages.

I know this can be done using GIS but as i want a batch process something in R would be

helpful.

Comment: `install.packages("sos"); library("sos"); findFn("thiessen")`

Comment: I am using ArcGIS for the same now ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You haven't given us access to your data, but here's an example for points representing cities of the world, using an approach described by Carson Farmer on [his blog](http://www.carsonfarmer.com/2009/09/voronoi-polygons-with-r/). Hopefully it'll get you started...

```
# Carson's Voronoi polygons function
voronoipolygons <- function(x) {
  require(deldir)
  require(sp)
  if (.hasSlot(x, 'coords')) {
    crds <- x@coords  
  } else crds <- x
  z <- deldir(crds[,1], crds[,2])
  w <- tile.list(z)
  polys <- vector(mode='list', length=length(w))
  for (i in seq(along=polys)) {
    pcrds <- cbind(w[[i]]$x, w[[i]]$y)
    pcrds <- rbind(pcrds, pcrds[1,])
    polys[[i]] <- Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)), ID=as.character(i))
  }
  SP <- SpatialPolygons(polys)
  voronoi <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data=data.frame(x=crds[,1],
    y=crds[,2], row.names=sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), 
    function(x) slot(x, 'ID'))))
}
```

**Example 1: Input is a SpatialPointsDataFrame:**

```
# Read in a point shapefile to be converted to a Voronoi diagram
library(rgdal)
dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
cities <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="cities")

v <- voronoipolygons(cities)

plot(v)
```

[image: Voronoi diagram of cities]

**Example 2: Input is vectors of x, y coordinates:**

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
v2 <- voronoipolygons(dat)
plot(v2)
```

[image: Another voronoi diagram]

Comment: I've modified the function so that it accepts vectors of coordinates (expected in order x, y) as well as a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`.

Comment: Is there any way I can do this for an irregular polygon boundary?
You can find my question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746150/r-calculating-thiessen-weights-for-an-area-with-irregular-boundary/29751220#29751220

Answer (score 3):

Same principle as shown by jbaums, but simpler code:

```
library(dismo)
library(rgdal)
cities <- shapefile(file.path(system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1], "cities"))

v <- voronoi(cities)
plot(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that [Voronoi cells are also known as Thiessen polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

Alternatively, one can make use of the [Simple Features for R](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/), specifically, the `sf::st_voronoi()` function. Below are examples inspired from [this help page](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_unary.html):

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1

# generate some random points
set.seed(2020-05-27)
n <- 50
points <- runif(n) %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 2) %>% 
  st_multipoint()

# Voronoi tesselation
voronoi_grid <- st_voronoi(points)

plot(voronoi_grid, col = NA)
plot(points, add = TRUE, col = "blue", pch = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Since you mentioned that you have multiple sets of points, one set for a year, you can make use of lists and iterate over them, for example:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1

# generate a list of length 20, each element containing with random points 
set.seed(2020-05-27)
yrs <- 20
n <- 50
points_lst <- vector(mode = "list", length = yrs)
for (i in 1:yrs) {
  points_lst[[i]] <- runif(n) %>% 
    matrix(ncol = 2) %>% 
    st_multipoint()
}

# Voronoi tesselation for each element of the list
voronoi_grids_lst <- lapply(points_lst, st_voronoi)

# plot 1st element
plot(voronoi_grids_lst[[1]], col = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>