# R - Delimit a Voronoi diagram according to a map

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, voronoi

I want to delimit a Voronoi diagram in a given map. I got inspired by the following questions to execute this task :

[Voronoi diagram polygons enclosed in geographic borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236698/voronoi-diagram-polygons-enclosed-in-geographic-borders?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Combine Voronoi polygons and maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156475/combine-voronoi-polygons-and-maps?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But something (maybe obvious) escapes me : I get the opposite result of what I expect. I want the diagram to be cut according to the map and not the map to be cut according to the diagram.

[image: Result]

Here is my code :

```
library(rgdal) ; library(rgeos) ; library(sp)
library(tmap) ; library(raster) ; library(deldir)

MyDirectory <- "" # the directory that contains the sph files

### Data ###
stores <- c("Paris", "Lille", "Marseille", "Nice", "Nantes", "Lyon", "Strasbourg")
lat <- c(48.85,50.62,43.29,43.71,47.21,45.76,48.57)
lon <- c(2.35,3.05,5.36,7.26,-1.55,4.83,7.75)

DataStores <- data.frame(stores, lon, lat)

coordinates(DataStores) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(DataStores) <- CRS("+proj=longlat")

### Map ###
# link : http://www.infosig.net/telechargements/IGN_GEOFLA/GEOFLA-Dept-FR-Corse-TAB-L93.zip
CountiesFrance <- readOGR(dsn = MyDirectory, layer = "LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT")

BordersFrance <- CountiesFrance[CountiesFrance$NATURE %in% c("Fronti\xe8re internationale","Limite c\xf4ti\xe8re"), ]

proj4string(BordersFrance) <- proj4string(DataStores)
BordersFrance <- spTransform(BordersFrance, proj4string(DataStores))

### Voronoi Diagramm ###
ResultsVoronoi <- PolygonesVoronoi(DataStores)

### Voronoi diagramm enclosed in geographic borders ###
proj4string(ResultsVoronoi) <- proj4string(DataStores)
ResultsVoronoi <- spTransform(ResultsVoronoi, proj4string(DataStores))

ResultsEnclosed <- gIntersection(ResultsVoronoi, BordersFrance, byid = TRUE)

plot(ResultsEnclosed)
points(x = DataStores$lon, y = DataStores$lat, pch = 20, col = "red", cex = 2)
lines(ResultsVoronoi)
```

And here is the `PolygonesVoronoi` function (thanks to the others posts and [Carson Farmer blog](http://carsonfarmer.com/2009/09/voronoi-polygons-with-r/)) :

```
PolygonesVoronoi <- function(layer) {
  require(deldir)
  crds = layer@coords
  z = deldir(crds[,1], crds[,2])
  w = tile.list(z)
  polys = vector(mode='list', length=length(w))
  require(sp)
  for (i in seq(along=polys)) {
    pcrds = cbind(w[[i]]$x, w[[i]]$y)
    pcrds = rbind(pcrds, pcrds[1,])
    polys[[i]] = Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)), ID=as.character(i))
  }
  SP = SpatialPolygons(polys)
  voronoi = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data=data.frame(x=crds[,1], 
                                                         y=crds[,2], row.names=sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), 
                                                                                      function(x) slot(x, 'ID'))))
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that the answers to both of the questions you linked used modified voronoi functions to limit the extent to a given polygon? Try replacing your `PolygonesVoronoi` with one of those modified `voronoipolygons` functions (note that you will need your map as a polygon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

```
library(dismo); library(rgeos)
library(deldir); library(maptools)

#data
stores <- c("Paris", "Lille", "Marseille", "Nice", "Nantes", "Lyon", "Strasbourg")
lat <- c(48.85,50.62,43.29,43.71,47.21,45.76,48.57)
lon <- c(2.35,3.05,5.36,7.26,-1.55,4.83,7.75)
d <- data.frame(stores, lon, lat)
coordinates(d) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(d) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

data(wrld_simpl)
fra <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$ISO3 == 'FRA', ]

# transform to a planar coordinate reference system (as suggested by @Ege Rubak)
prj <- CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80  +units=m")
d <- spTransform(d, prj)
fra <- spTransform(fra, prj)


# voronoi function from 'dismo'
# note the 'ext' argument to spatially extend the diagram
vor <- dismo::voronoi(d, ext=extent(fra) + 10)

# use intersect to maintain the attributes of the voronoi diagram
r <- intersect(vor, fra)

plot(r, col=rainbow(length(r)), lwd=3)
points(d, pch = 20, col = "white", cex = 3)
points(d, pch = 20, col = "red", cex = 2)

# or, to see the names of the areas
spplot(r, 'stores')
```

[image: voronoi diagram clipped with borders]

Comment: I guess the coordinates should strictly speaking be project to the plane since the planar Voronoi tessellation is used, but it may not make any difference for practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this with `terra`

```
library(terra)
stores <- c("Paris", "Lille", "Marseille", "Nice", "Nantes", "Lyon", "Strasbourg")
lat <- c(48.85,50.62,43.29,43.71,47.21,45.76,48.57)
lon <- c(2.35,3.05,5.36,7.26,-1.55,4.83,7.75)
d <- data.frame(stores, lon, lat)
d <- vect(d, crs="+proj=longlat")

library(geodata)
fra <- gadm(country='FRA', level=1, path=".")

# transform to a planar coordinate reference system (as suggested by @Ege Rubak)
prj <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +units=m"
dp <- project(d, prj)
fra <- project(fra, prj)

v <- voronoi(dp, fra)
vfra <- crop(v, fra)
vor <- project(vfra, "+proj=longlat")

plot(vor, "stores")
```

[image]