# Natural Neighbor Interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation, geospatial, spatial

I need to conduct Natural Neighbor Interpolation (NNI) via R in order to smooth my numeric data. For example, say I have very spurious data, my goal is to use NNI to model the data neatly.

I have several hundred rows of data (one observation for each postcode), alongside latitudes and longitudes. I've made up some data below:

```
Postcode lat        lon         Value
200      -35.277272 149.117136  7
221      -35.201372 149.095065  38
800      -12.801028 130.955789  27
801      -12.801028 130.955789  3
804      -12.432181 130.84331   29
810      -12.378451 130.877014  20
811      -12.376597 130.850489  3
812      -12.400091 130.913672  42
814      -12.382572 130.853877  32
820      -12.410444 130.856124  39
821      -12.426641 130.882367  39
822      -12.799278 131.131697  49
828      -12.474896 130.907378  38
829      -14.460879 132.280002  34
830      -12.487233 130.972637  8
831      -12.480066 130.984006  49
832      -12.492269 130.990891  29
835      -12.48138  131.029173  33
836      -12.525546 131.103025  40
837      -12.460094 130.842663  39
838      -12.709507 130.995407  28
840      -12.717562 130.351316  22
841      -12.801028 130.955789  8
845      -13.038663 131.072091  19
846      -13.226806 131.098416  50
847      -13.824123 131.835799  11
850      -14.464497 132.262021  2
851      -14.464497 132.262021  23
852      -14.92267  133.064654  36
854      -16.81839  137.14707   17
860      -19.648306 134.186642  3
861      -18.94406  134.318373  8
862      -20.231104 137.762232  28
870      -12.436101 130.84059   24
871      -12.436101 130.84059   16
```

Is there any kind of package that will do this? I should mention, that the only predictors I am using in this model are latitude and longitude. If there isn't a package than can do this, how can I implement it manually. I've searched extensively and I can't figure out how to implement this in R. I have seen [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614376/natural-neighbour-interpolation-error-in-calculating-polygon-intersection-area) or [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9405831/489704) other SO posts, but they haven't assisted me in figuring this out.

Please let me know if there's anything I must add to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue and inverse-distance weighting just isn't looking at nice as I'd like

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. Reproject the data to the corresponding UTM Zone.
2. Use [R WhiteboxTools](https://rdrr.io/rforge/whitebox/man/wbt_natural_neighbour_interpolation.html) package to process the data using natural neighbour interpolation.