# How can I label Thiessen (Voronoi) polygons

Tags: r, plot, gis

I would like to label Voronoi polygons with point attributes (in this case, station name and station number). To create Voronoi polygons, I used the function from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403660/how-to-create-thiessen-polygons-from-points-using-r-packages).

My station data file (shapefile) is in [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/2014r/SHP.zip).

```
pts <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer="rainfallStations")

thiessen.pol <- voronoipolygons(pts)
proj <- CRS('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84')
proj4string(thiessen.pol) <- proj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `text` with `coordinates`, e.g.:

```
plot(thiessen.pol)
text(coordinates(thiessen.pol), labels=pts$STA_NUMBER, cex=0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add attribute(station ID and name label) to thiessen.pol attribute table ?

Comment: @Nahm - You could try `thiessen.pol@data <- pts@data`.